# I have to send more than one file when the user click on submit in angular 6.And i am using form data to send data to API

Tags: angular6, form-data

Here is my code and i have to send more than one file through formdata to API

```
        for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        const K = "FileUpload" + i;
        if (event.target.name == K) {
            this.fu_Required = true;
            this.fileList= event.target.files;
            let file: File = this.fileList[0];
            this.fileSize = this.fileList[0].size;
            this.fileSizeValidate(file.size);
            this.formData = new FormData();
            file = this.fileList[0];
            this.formData.append(K, this.fileList[0]);              
        }

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What error are you running into?

Comment: If i hardcode the value of FileList0,Filelist1 like that 2 file it is taking.but for my case Filelist has to generate  dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are creating the formdata inside the loop so that may be the problem in your code try keeping `this.formData = new FormData();` outside the loop